# JavaScript function in Livecode Browser works on OSX, but not on Windows

Tags: javascript, windows, macos, livecode

I'm using Livecode to open a browser window, and then on that page call a JavaScript function, using the "revBrowserCallScript" function. The program was developed by a colleague that has since left the company, and I've recently found out that the JavaScript function only gets invoked (or at least executes) when run on OSX.

The comments section of the reference ([revBrowserCallScript reference](http://livecode.com/developers/api/6.0.2/function/revBrowserCallScript/)) does mention that it searches for and calls JScript functions on Windows and JavaScript functions on OSX, but I'm not sure if this actually is an issue, nor how to fix it.

I'm aware this is slightly vague, so if more information is needed, please let me know!

Thanks in advance for any help :)

Comment: Please, start with posting your code. At the least, post the part of the LiveCode script that calls the JavaScript function and post the JavaScript code. That will allow us to try it ourselves and will give us some understanding as to why it may not work.

Comment: I was hoping this would be a simple fix, something obvious I was just missing, hence the lack of code. I've actually started getting into it properly now, and it turns out the function is actually being called, but isn't resulting in the same functionality that I see running it in a normal browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure how, as according to all of the reference I've seen JS attempts to convert compared objects to the same type, but my issue was down to comparing different types.

I have a feeling this is something to do with the version of IE that Livecode is using as a browser, as a few things render differently compared to opening the html file directly in IE itself.

Anyway, the solution was fairly simple- in the JS function, I check if the passed parameter can be parsed into an integer, and then use this in the comparison.

```
    function getAssetFromId(assetId){

        if(parseInt(assetId) != 'NaN')
            assetId = parseInt(assetId);

        if(assetObject['id'] == assetId)
            return assetObject;
    }
```